# Github: Find PRs where user is a reviewer

Tags: github, pull-request

Github added [reviewers](https://github.com/blog/2291-introducing-review-requests).

Is there a way to find PRs (e.g. on the [Pull Requests](https://github.com/pulls) page) where the user is a reviewer? Things I have already tried:

- Checked https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues/ for a filter:

  None found
- Tested potential filters reviewer:{{user}}, review:{{user}}

  No PRs returned
- Tested the involved:{{user}} filter

  PRs with the user as only a reviewer are not shown in results.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

As of 2017-01-23, [Github have added this functionality](https://github.com/blog/2306-filter-pull-request-reviews-and-review-requests).

## [Search](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues/#search-pull-requests-by-review-status)

> You can filter pull requests based their review status (none,
> required, approved, changes requested, or required), by reviewer, and
> by requested reviewer. For example:
>
> **type:pr review:none**
> Matches pull requests that have not been reviewed.
>
> **type:pr review:required**
> Matches pull requests that require a review before they can be merged.
>
> **type:pr review:approved**
> Matches pull requests that a reviewer has approved.
>
> **type:pr review:changes_requested**
> Matches pull requests in which a reviewer has asked for changes.
>
> **type:pr reviewed-by:gjtorikian**
> Matches pull requests reviewed by a particular person.
>
> **type:pr review-requested:benbalter**
> Matches pull requests a particular person has been asked to review.

### [Personal PRs](https://github.com/pulls/review-requested)

A new tab can be seen on personal PR page https://github.com/pulls

## [Project PRs (e.g. Symfony)](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pulls?q=is%3Apr+is%3Aopen+review%3Aapproved)

A new filter can be seen on the project PR page e.g. https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pulls

Comment: Unfortunately, **pr reviewed-by:gjtorikian** seems to include PRs where gjtorikian made a comment on the review, rather than anyone who is listed as reviewer on the PR, and therefore approved or rejected it

Comment: @headinthecodes - I asked a follow up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75521612/251589

Comment: Any idea how to get all the reviews that I care about?  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76093811/find-prs-in-github-where-i-am-author-reviewer-or-assignee?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the easiest way, nowadays, to get this information, is to simply navigate to:

https://github.com/pulls/review-requested

Comment: PRs will disappear from this filter if you've reviewed them, which is probably what you don't want if you're looking for all PRs with reviewer.

Comment: @ray I guess it depends; if the "user" in question is yourself, this is probably exactly what you would want; if it's someone else, this may or may not be what you want

Comment: @ray, I agree.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76093811/find-prs-in-github-where-i-am-author-reviewer-or-assignee

Answer (score 4):

You have now also access to `is:open is:pr user-review-requested:@me` that is a little different from the others because it will only filter the PRs you are explicitly asked as a reviewer (team review dont count).

Comment: This one works as long as you have not given your review yet. As soon as you give your review the PR won't appear anymore using this query.

Answer (score 2):

I just came across this, because I wanted to search for PRs that got a review from a specific user.

`is:pr reviewed-by:USERNAME`

Source https://docs.github.com/en/issues/tracking-your-work-with-issues/filtering-and-searching-issues-and-pull-requests

> Filter pull requests by reviewer: `state:open type:pr reviewed-by:octocat`