# Github: Find PRs that I have reviewed (but not created)

Tags: github, pull-request

I am trying to figure out how many PRs I have reviewed in the last 6 months, but haven't been able to extract this info from Github.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41506891/github-find-prs-where-user-is-a-reviewer), to a very similar question suggests that you should use this:

```
type:pr reviewed-by:gjtorikian
```

Unfortunately, this returns PRs that I have created AND PRs that I have reviewed:

[image]

Is there a way that I can query for PRs that I have reviewed by not PRs that I have created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you can exclude the creator like this:

```
is:pr reviewed-by:JakeSummers -author:JakeSummers
```

The `-` is used to exclude.

Comment: What about only PRs approved by me? Can the username be dynamic for the current user so it's bookmarkable?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/JakeSummers includes a monthly summary of how many PRs that user has reviewed.  This helped me work out who were the slackers in the team :-) (actually there weren't any).