# Find PRs in GitHub where I am author, reviewer, or assignee

Tags: github, pull-request

From GitHub.com, I'd like to see all open PRs where I am the author, reviewer, or assignee, whether as an individual or as a member of a team.

From [github.com/pulls](https://github.com/pulls), I can filter with something like `is:open is:pr author:@me` but effectively I would like to OR or UNION such a filter.  Ideally, I wish I could do something like the following, where '|' is the OR operator--but sadly this doesn't work: `is:open is:pr author:@me|reviewed-by:@me|review-requested:@me|mentions:@me`.

Any idea how I might do this?  [This answer was helpful but doesn't go far enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41506891/github-find-prs-where-user-is-a-reviewer).

Comment: I'm guessing you never found an answer for this? I'm struggling to find a single place to see the PRs I'm involved in

Comment: @Mendhak, that's right.  It would help to upvote the question.

Answer (score 3):

I think I finally have the answer. I wanted to see all the PRs in which I am mentioned or requested. The `involves` filter does this job. Although Github search *still* doesn't support OR, the `involves` filter is doing an OR behind the scenes.

```
is:open is:pr involves:@me archived:false
```

So try this link and it should work:

https://github.com/pulls?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Apr+involves%3A%40me+archived%3Afalse+

Description of the [involves filter](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests#search-by-a-user-thats-involved-in-an-issue-or-pull-request):

> You can use the involves qualifier to find issues that in some way involve a certain user. The involves qualifier is a logical OR between the author, assignee, mentions, and commenter qualifiers for a single user. In other words, this qualifier finds issues and pull requests that were either created by a certain user, assigned to that user, mention that user, or were commented on by that user.

Comment: The `involves:@me` filter doesn't show PRs where one of my teams is on as a reviewer.  That's what I really want, in addition to all that `involves:@me` shows.